# Rational Expression Simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The function:

$$f(x) = \frac{3x - 4}{x^2 - 2x}$$

is simplified to:

$$f(x) = \frac{2}{x} + \frac{1}{x - 2}$$

How? And in what way?

Comment: Have you read about partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: Could you show me the (PFD)=

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We would like to write $\dfrac{3x-4}{x^2-2x} = \dfrac{3x-4}{x(x-2)}$ in the form $\dfrac{A}{x} + \dfrac{B}{x-2}$ for some constants $A,B$.

Now, we just need to solve for $A,B$. First, let's get rid of fractions:

$\dfrac{A}{x} + \dfrac{B}{x-2} = \dfrac{3x-4}{x(x-2)}$

$A(x-2)+Bx = 3x-4$

This equality must be true for all values of $x$, so it must be true for $x = 0$ and $x = 2$:

Plugging in $x = 0$ gives us $A \cdot (0-2) + B \cdot 0 = 3 \cdot 0 - 4$, i.e. $-2A = -4$. Hence, $A = 2$.

Plugging in $x = 2$ gives us $A \cdot (2-2) + B \cdot 2 = 3 \cdot 2 - 4$, i.e. $2B = 2$. Hence, $B = 1$.

Therefore, $\dfrac{3x-4}{x(x-2)} = \dfrac{2}{x} + \dfrac{1}{x-2}$.

You can also solve $A(x-2)+Bx = 3x-4$, by writing it as $(A+B)x+2A = 3x-4$, and equating coefficients. Then, you get the equations $A+B = 3$ and $2A = -4$. Solving this linear system gives $A = 2$ and $B = 1$ as you got with the first method.

Note: This technique is called Partial Fraction Decomposition. I suggest you Google that term for more information on this method.

Comment: Small typo.  Those $x+2$'s should be $x-2$

Comment: ^Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=\frac {3x-4}{x^2-2x}\\
=\frac {3x-4}{x(x-2)}\\
=\frac Ax +\frac B{x-2}\\
=\frac {A(x-2)+Bx}{x(x-2)}$$

Equation numerators:
$$3x-4=A(x-2)+Bx\\
=(A+B)x-2A$$
gives $A=2,B=1$, i.e.

$$f(x)=\frac {3x-4}{x^2-2x}=\frac 2x +\frac 1{x-2}$$